# TypeError: string indices must be integers -python

Tags: python-3.x

I am using `pubmed_lookup` package in python, for some reasons, I got an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers ;
```

and I cannot see what's wrong. I haven't got the foggiest idea about this error!

```
with open ('file location','r') as f:
    urls =[line.strip() for line in f]


lookup = [ ]
for url in urls:
        lookup.append (PubMedLookup(url,email))
i = 0
while True:
    publication = Publication(lookup[i])
    print(
        """
JOURNAL:\n{journal}\n
"""
        .format(**{
            'journal':publication.journal,
            }))
    i +=1
    if i >3:
        break
```

My file format is as follows.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28483699   
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26318800   
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28766011

Thanks a lot!!!

The error statement might be this: 
publication  = Publication(lookup[i])

Comment: btw there is no need in `dict` unpacking, just pass parameters as keywords like `.format(journal=publication.journal)`

Comment: which statement causes this error?

Comment: I think it may be the "while True" statement.

Comment: there is no string literals in `while True:`, update question with full traceback

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried last night, and I thought maybe this statement: 
 publication = Publication(lookup[i])
thanks